# Android SDK error: Trying instantiate a class that is not a fragment

Tags: android, class, sdk, fragment, instantiation

I am hardly trying to create a simple application with a top menu and a changeable view below (by pressing the buttons in the menu fragment we change the view of the fragment below).
So, I have 2 fragments inside the main view but when trying to run the application in the emulator I get an error like:

```
Cause by android.app (bla bla bla, piece of crap Eclipse doesn't even allow copying the errors): 
Trying to instantiate a class com.example.android.topmenu that is not a fragment
```

So, these are my XML layouts:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:name="com.example.android.topmenu" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:name="com.example.android.bottomcontent" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

**topmenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/Button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**bottom_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/content_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and these are the classes for the main activity and the fragments

**main_activity**

```
package com.example.android;

import com.example.android.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class OLife extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The activity is being created
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // The activity is about to be destroyed.
        super.onDestroy();

        // Stop method tracing that the activity started during onCreate()
        android.os.Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    }
}
```

**topmenu**

```
package com.example.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class OLifeMenu extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topmenu, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**bottomcontent**

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class OLifeMain extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_content, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it. The API, tutorials, examples, everything looks so messed up

Comment: ill put it as answer so the future googlers will see it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should be using `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` that is because you are using support Fragments and multiple Fragments in your activity main

---

**Edit**

You can now use the [Appcompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) support library and extends `AppCompatActivity` to support toolbar and fragment for lower api.

Comment: Or use any of the other derivatives like `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't imagine how long it would have taken me to find that one.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it turned out, I was doing stuff in `onCreate` in the wrong order:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr_code_scan);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

instead of

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr_code_scan);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using fragments in your layout and I suggest you to extend your class from fragment or fragment activity.