# My Android App Crashes down when i add Fragment to XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

This is Main Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="#71b7d6"
        tools:context="com.csdelta.haroon.fragmentpractice.MainActivity">
<!--Binary XML file line #13  --> 
 <fragment    
        android:id="@+id/my_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.csdelta.haroon.fragmentpractice.MyFragment"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is Fragment Activity XML

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f7dc0f"
        tools:context="com.csdelta.haroon.fragmentpractice.MyFragment">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello, This is Fragment"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is Main Activity Java File

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Haroon", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Here is Fragment Java File

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Haroon", "onCreateView");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

The logcat message which i get says:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.csdelta.haroon.fragmentpractice/com.csdelta.haroon.fragmentpractice.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML
>   file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
>                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class
>   fragment
>                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
>                         Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a
>   class com.csdelta.haroon.fragmentpractice.MyFragment

that is not a Fragment

Here is the complete LogCat:
https://pastebin.com/iss7ui16

Comment: in your case you should use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK error: Trying instantiate a class that is not a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213756/android-sdk-error-trying-instantiate-a-class-that-is-not-a-fragment)

Comment: Thank You very much. It worked by extending to FragmentActivity instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think your fragment extending support Fragment, so your activity need to extend AppCompatActivity and not Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Covert fragment to FrameLayout tag like that

```
<FrameLayout   
    android:id="@+id/my_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.csdelta.haroon.fragmentpractice.MyFragment"/>
```

Comment: It's still not working.Actually, I want to add fragment using XML. Following the actually procedure but don't what's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the same error, just try FrameLayout as

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"/>
```

and call the fragment as

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your MainActivity to this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.my_frag, new MyFragment()).commit();
 }
}
```